# For loop is repeating after finish and returning ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, for-loop, repeat

I'm passing a foreach to a for to improve performance. However, I think my for is fine but, after its runs, I don't know why it repeat 1 more last time (even it's not corresponding to the sentence) and it throws error because the `i` doesn't exist in that list.

I've searched and no one had this error so I'm curious. I mean the condition is fine and it works fine "the first time" but then, from nowhere it runs again and breaks.

It could be possible because I'm doing a `ToList()` for the `list1`? Because calling to the data base returns an `IEnumerable` and I couldn't use it for the `For` loop.

```
var list1 = GetData1FromDB().ToList();
var list2 = GetData2FromDB();

for (int i = 0; i <= list1.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    var data2 = list2.Where(x => x.Id == list1[i].Id);
    list1[i].Details = data2;
    result.data1.Add(list1[i]);
}
```

Comment: I can't really understand what the problem is. What's the exact error and which line throws it?

Comment: It breaks in this line
            var data2 = list2.Where(x => x.Id == list1[i].Id);
Because list1.Count is 6, when i < 6 it goes fine, but after running the foreach and returning the post to the web... the code breaks from nowhere in that line because i now is 6 and the list goes from 0 to 5

Comment: `i <= list1.Count() - 1` is the same as `i < list1.Count()`. Also use the `list1.Count` property instead of the `list1.Count()` extension method.

Comment: Ok, I've changed all that, but the error stills

Comment: Oh. Delayed execution. Add a `.ToList()` to that `= data2;`.

Comment: Man! It works! Great, thanks!!
Now I don't get it, what was happening?

Comment: Also, I would suggest adding `list2` stuff into a dictionary instead for speed. `var dict = GetData2FromDB().ToDictionary(x => x.Id);` then, in the loop: `list1[i].Details = dict[list1[i].Id];`. This is O(n). The list variant is O(n^2).

Comment: Hi Olivier, the problem is that Details is waiting for IEnumerable<list1>  (or a list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is delayed execution / lazy evaluation [caused by LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) (see *Remarks* section). When you do this:

```
var data2 = list2.Where(x => x.Id == list1[i].Id);
list1[i].Details = data2;
```

You've created an IEnumerable which knows to return elements from `list2` where the `x.Id == list1[i].Id`. But it has not yet actually executed that logic - it's just remembered "how" to do it, including which variables it needs to reference.

It will execute later, when something actually tries to enumerate it. The problem is that later, the value of the `i` variable has changed to an out of range value (because `i` is incremented by the `for` loop until it's out of range).

You can force the `IEnumerable` to execute immediately, by adding `.ToList()` to the end. This will enumerate it and put the contents into a list.

For more explanation on lambdas capturing variables, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: Yes this solved my problem! Thank you guys.
Thanks for the info!